# Using php within a href but keeping on the same page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, silex

Basically I have a href that passes through the id of an image via json which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4567/public/vote.html?image=50b4d006fa4634bb130000fe
```

this then creates/updates an image in mongo based on the id and updates if the user/visitor has voted.

at the moment i use silex to redirect after the code within that vote.html has been processed:

```
 return $app->redirect('popular.html');
```

i was wondering if it was possible to use jquery to process the above href without redirecting, so basically i could click vote and the number would change seamlessly without the user knowing they have been redirected.

### answered

sorry for the vague question but my answer does come from the principle of that posted below.

i changed the href to assign a class of vote & the id of the image:

```
<a class="vote" id="' + image.id + '" href="#">
```

then added this to my $(document).ready function:

```
$(".vote").live('click', function() {
        $('span', this).toggle();
        $.ajax( site_url + 'vote.html?image=' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

this in theory uses the id of the mongo object and appends it to the url for each time the object is clicked, processing the href without redirecting.

Comment: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: you could use ajax to update or create the row in the database then just increment your div with the votes like $('#num_votes').html(parseInt($('#num_votes').html())++);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a bit of jQuery to help you out. This is a very contrived example, as you have not provided any HTML markup examples for your vote buttons / images.

```
$(function() { // anything in here will happen once the DOM is ready
    $('.vote').click(function(e) { // assign click for each elem w/ class "vote" 
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action (if elem was an anchor)
        // Make the server request asynchronously
        var $this = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // or "GET"; or use $.post()/$.get() 
            url: $(this).attr("href"), // the href of the anchor
            data: null // or JSON here (e.g. { 'id': 'abcde' })
        }).done(function(data) { // vote.html should be image data of some kind
            // update the DOM with the new vote image
            // possible example if response was base64 encoded png
            $($this).closest('image').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use AJAX to update the number? Really simple with [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Is there any way you can expound on the answer, and provide just a tad more detail? Welcome to Stack Overflow, where we try and have rather lengthy answers, not one liners (plus you gain rep when you write good answers)

Answer (score -1):

You can override the click event in jQuery like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // DO MY STUFF HERE
});
```

Comment: What gives - the question as I read it is -  if it was possible to use jquery to process the above href without redirecting.

Comment: this code will not process anything. It will simply stop the 'click' from doing anything. While this code would be required to stop a redirect upon a click of the anchor tag, the code required to 'process' the request (which is the main question) does not exist in your example

Comment: I still don't see where the OP is asking how to do the behind the scenes mongo work, the OP is simply asking " if it was possible to use jquery to process the above href without redirecting".  That is what I  answered.  If the OP needs anything beyond that it should be stated in the question.  Either way it doesn't deserve a down-vote imho.

Comment: yes i was only asking if it was possible, and perhaps what approach to take.